# jQuery Accordion problem

Tags: jquery, accordion

HI all.

I have this very simple code for simple accordion.

```
$('div.header').click(function() {
            $('div.content').slideUp('normal');
            $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
        }); $("div.content").hide();
```

HTML

```
<div class="header">Header</div>
<div class="content">Content... </div>
```

So whenever header is being click content expands.

the problem is that when I click on the same header content slides up and going back down.

I'm not sure how to sort this out.

Any help much appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use slideToggle()

```
$('div.header').click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle('normal');
    }); $("div.content").hide();
```

http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Answer (score 0):

You could determine if the content is already visible before sliding using

```
if ((object-you-want-to-check).is(':visible') )
```